# Unbaking mojibake

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, decoding, mojibake

When you have incorrectly decoded characters, how can you identify likely candidates for the original string?

```
Ä×èÈÄÄî▒è¤ô_üiâAâjâüâpâXüj_10òb.png
```

I know for a fact that this image filename should have been some Japanese characters.  But with various guesses at urllib quoting/unquoting, encode and decode iso8859-1, utf8, I haven't been able to unmunge and get the original filename.

Is the corruption reversible?

Comment: I'm impressed you figured out it was Japanese just from that gobbledygook.

Comment: It is not from the gobbledygook itself.  I know that from the context in which I received the gobbledygook

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use chardet (install with pip):

```
import chardet

your_str = "Ä×èÈÄÄî▒è¤ô_üiâAâjâüâpâXüj_10òb"
detected_encoding = chardet.detect(your_str)["encoding"]

try:
    correct_str = your_str.decode(detected_encoding)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    print("Could not estimate encoding")
```

Result: 時間試験観点（アニメパス）_10秒 (no idea if this could be correct or not)

For Python 3 (source file encoded as utf8):

```
import chardet
import codecs

falsely_decoded_str = "Ä×èÈÄÄî¦è¤ô_üiâAâjâüâpâXüj_10òb"

try:
    encoded_str = falsely_decoded_str.encode("cp850")
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print("could not encode falsely decoded string")
    encoded_str = None

if encoded_str:
    detected_encoding = chardet.detect(encoded_str)["encoding"]

    try:
        correct_str = encoded_str.decode(detected_encoding)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("could not decode encoded_str as %s" % detected_encoding)

    with codecs.open("output.txt", "w", "utf-8-sig") as out:
        out.write(correct_str)
```

In summary:

```
>>> s = 'Ä×èÈÄÄî▒è¤ô_üiâAâjâüâpâXüj_10òb.png'
>>> s.encode('cp850').decode('shift-jis')
'時間試験観点（アニメパス）_10秒.png'
```

Comment: Google Translate says "Test time point of view (animation path) _10 seconds", looks almost sensible!

Comment: This looks very cool and promising, but I am getting a different result to you.  Do you run code just as shown here?  Which python and chardet version numbers?

Comment: I ran this on Python 2.7.7 + chardet 2.2.1. With Python 3 this definitely does not work, I'll have a look at how to do that.

Comment: As this above includes a byte string with non-ASCII characters, what happens depends on the encoding you save the source file in. As the string `Ä×èÈÄÄî▒è¤ô_üiâAâjâüâpâXüj_10òb` is the result of a code page 932-encoded (Shift-JIS-like) string being misinterpreted as code page 850 (DOS Western European), the source above would have to be saved as cp850 to work.

Comment: I have added a solution for python 3 above thanks to the comment of @bobince

Comment: The python3 version works for me, but @bobince how did you know those encodings?  That is the guts of this question, and in this current answer, the important part ("cp850") is hardcoded!

Comment: With this type of encoding problem, the encoding would also be constant, it is safe to assume cp850 in situations where the python 2 implementation would work. It is the actual encoding (SHIFT_JIS) that you have to estimate. There is no guaranteed way to determine encoding, especially not if false encoding is first applied anyway. I think the above should help in most common cases, else I look forward to more examples.

Comment: The selection of accented characters tells me you have a Western European encoding and the presence of the box drawing character `▒` implies a DOS encoding, so put those together and you probably have 850 (or conceivably 437). "Japanese" implies that the encoding that should have been used instead is either a UTF, or one of the Japanese-specific MBCSs. As what you have is probably 850, you are probably using Windows, so likely it's the old Windows default code page for Japanese-locale installations, 932.

Comment: This was my heuristic approach based on previous experience; clearly it doesn't translate practically to automated detection. What you would probably do if trying to solve programmatically would be to have a rating function for "looks most like the target language" and try encoding and re-decoding using all combinations of the encodings Python knows about in turn. The unmangled text may not always be recoverable: there are many encodings in which not every byte maps to a character, so characters that used those bytes in the real-encoding would be lost.