# python replace unicode characters

Tags: python, mojibake

I wrote a program to read in Windows DNS debugging log, but inside always got some funny characters in the domain field.

Below is one of the example:

```
(13)\xc2\xb5\xc2\xb1\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa2p\xc3\xb4\xc2\x8d(5)example(3)com(0)'
```

I want to replace all the `\x..` with a `?`

I explicitly type \xc2 as follows works

```
line = '(13)\xc2\xb5\xc2\xb1\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa2p\xc3\xb4\xc2\x8d(5)example(3)com(0)'
re.sub('\\\xc2', '?', line)
result: '(13)?\xb5?\xb1?\xbe\xc3\xa2p\xc3\xb4?\x8d(5)example(3)com(0)'
```

But its not working if I write as follow:

`re.sub('\\\x..', '?', line)`

How I can write a regular expression to replace them all?

Comment: Purely as an exersize for the reader - `re.sub('[\x80-\xff]', '?', line)`. but please don't do that, @wim's answer is what you should go for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are better tools for this job than regex, you could try for example:

```
>>> line
'(13)\xc2\xb5\xc2\xb1\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa2p\xc3\xb4\xc2\x8d(5)example(3)com(0)'
>>> line.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
u'(13)p(5)example(3)com(0)'
```

That skips non-ascii characters.  Or with replace, you can swap them for a '?' placeholder:

```
>>> print line.decode('ascii', 'replace')
(13)��������p����(5)example(3)com(0)
```

But the best solution is to find out what erroneous encoding/decoding caused the [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) to happen in the first place, so you can recover data by using the correct code pages.

There is an excellent answer about unbaking emojibake [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24141326/674039).  Note that it's an inexact science, and a lot of the crucial information is actually in the comment thread under that answer.

Answer (score -2):

what about this?

```
line = '(13)\xc2\xb5\xc2\xb1\xc2\xbe\xc3\xa2p\xc3\xb4\xc2\x8d(5)example(3)com(0)'

pattern = r'\\x.+'
re.sub(pattern, r'?', line)
```

Comment: This is wholly incorrect. The string is not a series of `\ ` and `x` characters followed by a pair of alphanumeric characters, the `\xNN`s are a representation of a byte outside the ASCII range. The `__repr__` of a python string (ambiguous term) catches these bytes and prints a representation of their hex value.

Comment: No, this is not working because \xc2 is not regarded as a normal string, this whole 'string' cannot be treated as a combination of individuals characters.

Comment: No, this is not working because \xc2 is not regarded as a normal string, this whole 'string' cannot be treated as a combination of individuals characters. I found that I can use range of values in regex for this: re.sub(r'[\x03]|[\x8d]|[\xa0-\xaf]|[\xb0-\xbf]|[\xc0-\xcf]|[\xd0-\xdf]', '', line). But the downside is I need to know in advance the possible ranges in order to come up with this range.

Comment: @kenneth171 Check my comment on the question. Ascii only uses `\x00-\x7f`, so you can use the range `\x80-\xff`.