# Convert mojibake to Korean in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, android-contacts, mojibake, korean-nlp

(Edited: now referencing [Unbaking mojibake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140497/unbaking-mojibake#24141326))

Source file: Android phone .vcf contacts file
Destination: Windows 7 User Contacts file (imported .vcf)

Resulting contact info: 
Korean mojibake for the Name Field: 
'_곗퐫 李쏀__ㅻ━肄섏떎留_'

The result should be only Korean text. After doing a bit of research, I'm guessing there is some encoding problems related to `EUC-kr` because of the Chinese characters in the mojibake. But really have no idea...

Using code modified from [Unbaking mojibake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140497/unbaking-mojibake#24141326)

this is the Python results:
_°ì¤Ô¤½¤É¤§ ì°½í__¤ë¦¬ì½¤Ô¤µ¤Â¤°¤Ô¤¨¤Â¤«ë§_

Obviously it's not correct. So still stuck...

```
# ?'windows-1252' -> 949?
encoding1 = 'ISO-2022-KR' #could not encode
encoding1 = 'windows-1252' #could not encode
encoding1 = 'iso-8859-1' #could not encode
encoding1 = 'utf8' #does nothing
encoding1 = 'euc-kr'

import chardet

import chardet
import codecs

mojibake = '_곗퐫 李쏀__ㅻ━肄섏떎留_'

try:
    encoded_str = mojibake.encode(encoding1)
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    print("error: could not encode")
    encoded_str = None

if encoded_str:
    detected_encoding = chardet.detect(encoded_str)["encoding"]
    print('detected_encoding',detected_encoding)
    try:
        correct_str = encoded_str.decode(detected_encoding)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("could not decode encoded_str as", detected_encoding)

    print(correct_str)
```

Comment: Are you sure your text you are getting to begin with is actually wrong?

Comment: What would a correct version of your mojibake string look like? Only Korean, no Chinese characters?

Comment: The result should have no Chinese characters...The Korean letters currently showing in the mojibake are not correct.